# Pandas csv.read pulling csv columns as string instead of integers and inputting them in the first column of database as single argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dataset

I have been trying to build a script in python that pulls the info from a set of csv files. The format of the csv is as follows and has no header: ['Day','Hour','Seconds','Microsecods','x_accel','y_accel']. Instead of inputting the values in the correspondent columns pandas is pulling the values and making them a string like this:" 9,40,19,65664,-0.527,-0.333" in the first column. I tried using dtype and sep=',' but did not work. I don't understand why it does not fit them properly in the right columns.

This is my script:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('C:/Users/pc/Desktop/41x/Learning_set/Bearing1_1')
path = os.getcwd()

files = os.listdir(path)

df = pd.DataFrame()
columns = ['Day','Hour','Seconds','Microsecods','x_accel','y_accel']
for f in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(f, 'Sheet1', header = None,engine='python',names=columns)
    df = df.append(data)
    
    
print(df)
```

This is the pd output db:

[image]

This is snap of the csv:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `read_csv` function but in your arguments you are implying that the separator value is 'Sheet1':

```
pd.read_csv(f, 'Sheet1', header=None, engine='python', names=columns)
```

Is it a CSV or is it from an Excel file. If it is a CSV then most likely you can just remove this and it will work as expected.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please consider upvoting and accept as the answer.